# FAIL - Application at context path /MyProject could not be started (JndiException and NameNotFoundException)

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my project on Tomcat 7. I included

at tomcat/config/context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/MyProjectDS"
             global="jdbc/MyProjectDS"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

and

at tomcat/config/server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyProjectDS" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="5" maxWait="30000"
    username="username" password="password"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    validationQuery="Select 1"
    url="jdbc:mysql://10.15.101.73:3306/myproject?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

but it returns the exceptions as follow:

```
Aug 09, 2017 2:41:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter naviox
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.getEntityManagerFactory(XPersistence.java:197)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.createManager(XPersistence.java:112)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.openManager(XPersistence.java:128)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.getManager(XPersistence.java:98)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.isAutoUpdateSchema(DB.java:173)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.createDB(DB.java:153)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.init(DB.java:32)
    at com.openxava.naviox.Modules.init(Modules.java:38)
    at com.openxava.naviox.web.NaviOXFilter.init(NaviOXFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java://comp/env/jdbc/MyProjectDS]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyProjectDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceLinkFactory.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 60 more
```

At myproject/hibernate.cfg.xml, I have the following codes:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Tomcat + Hypersonic -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java://comp/env/jdbc/MyProjectDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</property>     
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>

        <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool provider -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">300</property> <!-- 5 minutes -->

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

At persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <!-- Tomcat + Hypersonic -->
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java://comp/env/jdbc/AdunFormsDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>org.openxava.session.GalleryImage</class>
        <class>org.openxava.web.editors.DiscussionComment</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>
```

I have no idea why these exceptions appear since this is my first time deploying a project on a tomcat server. I tried to google the solution but none of them solve my problem. I hope that someone can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realize that my project's folder is not auto-deployed but it is visible in Tomcat Web Application Manager. Is this the reason that causes my problem?

Comment: Add JDBC Driver to tomcat ....  and let us see your java code conf or xml conf that make a call to the Datasource

Comment: @Yugerten, updated my question as your request. To answer "Add JDBC Driver to tomcat", I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar in tomcat/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

I checked the catalina.log and realized that the exception is due to the version of icu4j.jar file is too old. Just simply replace it with a latest version will do.

Gained knowledge: Catalina.log does output exceptions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java://comp/env/jdbc/MyProjectDS</property> <!-- name & JNDI url-->
```

try to change property name & JNDI url as below

```
<property name="datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/MyProjectDS</property>
```

hope that help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still displays the same exceptions.

Comment: @BrianCheong , the problem is that you hibernate is configured to use **SessionFactory** but not **EntityManager**, in this case if you want  to choose **Hibernate SessionFactory** then you must modify your java code to use "SessionFactory". In the other case if you want to use EntityManager you must update the configuration and use persistence.xml and create **EntityManagerFactory** from hibernate conf

Answer (score 0):

For EntityManager use with hibernate:

follow this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration-packaging) for more information about **persistance.xml** conf file

Get the EntityManager:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManFac = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("yourpersistenceUnitName");
 // your persistance.xml 
//<persistence-unit name="yourpersistenceUnitName">
//provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 // <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
EntityManager entityManager = entityManFac.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: by default my JPA project has persistence.xml file. updated in my question.